# Wordpress files not found when I can to make the restore on a diffrent hosting file

Tags: wordpress, backup

I’m a newbie on Wordpress and when I transfer my domain to a diffrent hosting account and come to restore the bckup files I found it as shown on the second picture which was suppose to be like pic1 this shows that the wp-content,admin,includes etc aren’t appearing on the backup what could be the resin and how can I restore my website again ???

Have the zipped backup and the .sql backup!

Comment: Do you have any screenshots you can attach?

Comment: Yes I have some screenshots but can’t upload it because I just registered and it needs reputation

Comment: In that case can you be more specific in regards to what errors you're seeing? Migrating WordPress can be tricky if you've never done it before, I suggest taking a look at the official documentation https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: When it comes to the restore method it uploads the backup file that I was having but gave error 404 and when I checked the backup files that I use to have it doesn’t seem like the usual Wordpress backup files because the wp- files are missing and wondering if that’s something normal

Answer (score 0):

When you moved the folders to a different hosting along with the database you didn't change the URLs. WordPress is still searching for those pictures under your first http://whatever.link.it.was.url.

If you still have access to the old hosting, try this plugin: https://hu.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

If not..well... you only thing left is the hacky way, changing those URL by hand like in the above-mentioned link (https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)